# How to specify Authorization Header for a source in mapbox-gl-js?

Tags: http-headers, authorization, mapbox-gl-js

How do I set a request header for a wms source with mapbox-gl-js?  I need all tile requests to add a header that looks like:

```
Authorization: "Bearer base64-encoded-token"
```

The [WMS example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/wms/), [map#addSource](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map#addSource) and [map#addLayer](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map#addLayer) lead me to believe it is not possible to set tile request headers.

Comment: Same issue here but with vector tile source. Did you find a way to add this header?

Comment: I'm using OpenLayers-3, which doesn't have the problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can now use the [`transformRequest`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map) option to add a custom header:

> A callback run before the Map makes a request for an external URL. The callback can be used to modify the url, set headers, or set the credentials property for cross-origin requests. Expected to return an object with a `url` property and optionally `headers` and `credentials` properties.

Example:

```js
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  center: [2.35, 48.86],
  zoom: 13,
  transformRequest: (url, resourceType) => {
    if (resourceType === 'Source' && url.startsWith('http://myHost')) {
      return {
        url: url,
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + yourAuthToken }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Steve Bennett and ThunderDev, does this still works with current GL JS release? I am sending authorization to server but my map is not authorizing.

Comment: Mapbox's api docs still mention this option along with an similar example, so yes, I believe it should still work with the current release. You might have a problem with your auth token.

Comment: @ThunderDev if I understand correctly, this would add a 'hidden' authorization code in the `header` of the request so others can't peep into the browser's network tools and use my token? I am integrating it in Wordpress and your reply would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @RagingVids I think you are talking about your mapbox access token, this cannot be hidden unfortunatly.

Comment: @ThunderDev maybe I am missing something then, how could anyone protect their tokens then? Is it even fair to openly make them visible so anyone can come in and enjoy free map loads off of others? I'm not too experienced in network calls so please excuse me for the naivety.

Comment: @RagingVids usually there is a domain restriction, eg. a token is only valid if called from your specific domain. If you need more information on this, I would suggest to open a new question if that's ok with you.

Comment: @ThunderDev I would do that but the community has been unwelcoming lately, down votes for no reason. And I do provide screenshots and codes for reference. Anyway, thanks.