# Intercept Mapbox Geowebcache tiles request in Angular application

Tags: http, request, interceptor, mapbox-gl-js, intercept

I'm using Angular 7 with Mapbox GL JS library, and some Geoserver GeoWebcache Tiles are taking long time to be shown in the map.

I would need to cache the response of the .pbf loaded in this process in order to don't make a new request if the response is currently available, but although I'm using Angular HTTP Interceptor and pure JavaScript interceptor, the pbf requests are shown in my Google Chrome network tab but is not logged and intercepted by any of the used interceptors.

How can I intercept those specific requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following thread for a solution for interception mapboxgl requests.
In this case for authorization purposes.
[How to specify Authorization Header for a source in mapbox-gl-js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940860/how-to-specify-authorization-header-for-a-source-in-mapbox-gl-js)