# Mapbox: How many tiles were requested by this api key/account

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

is there a way to request how many tiles were already requested this month for a given API key?
Or would I need a backend, to keep track?
On this side, I can see the requested tiles: https://account.mapbox.com/ 
But it only updates daily, not live.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't look like that's exposed in the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `transformRequest` option you can use when you instantiate the map.  You could add code to it to trigger a counter somewhere else whenever a tile is requested.

See `options.transformRequest` here:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map

Here is an example of how it is used: [How to specify Authorization Header for a source in mapbox-gl-js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940860/how-to-specify-authorization-header-for-a-source-in-mapbox-gl-js)